# Вопрос выживания и вопрос о выживании. В чем заключается разница в смысле?

Tags: смысл

*Вопрос выживания и вопрос о выживании*.
В чем заключается разница в смысле?

Comment: Смысловой разницы по факту нет, ибо обе фразы могут употребляться в сходных контекстах. Грамматическая разница есть.

Answer (score 1):

‟ Вопрос выживания ” говорят тогда, когда предмет текущего обсуждения является ключевых фактором в выживании. Например, в зомби-апокалипсисе люди могут говорить о нехватке оружия, и кто-то может сказать: ‟ Это вопрос выживания ”, чтобы подчеркнуть важность получения оружия.
Когда кто-то спрашивает об особенностях, методах, секретах выживания в дикой местности, например, на каком-нибудь семинаре по данной тематике, то данный вопрос можно обозначить сочетанием ‟ вопрос о выживании ”.

Answer (score 0):

Я разницы особой не увидел:

1. "Вопрос о выживании уже не стоит. Но, после того как нижний уровень потребностей пройден, пирамида Маслоу разваливается".
2. "Ограничение расходов и более справедливое распределение доходов — это вопрос выживания".

Чувственно: "Вопрос выживания" — звучит более угнетающе, если необходимо акцентировать внимание на важности проблемы, то я бы сказал: "Вопрос выживания".